# regex - match everything except certain strings

Tags: regex, scala

To verify the regex for my purposes I use the Scala console with:
`"REGEX".r.findFirstIn("exampleString").isDefinied`

I have a lot of Strings, which I want to match with regex.
Whenever the String is exactly "foo" or "bar", I want the above to be false.

The closest I got is `^((?!foo|bar).)*$`.
The problem with this is though, that everything is false once it contains either "foo" or "bar", although I would want "foof" to be true.

UPDATE:
I do need this regex for the configuration of a script. So I can't use Scala methods or change the way the regex is handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not allow only those strings that do **not** match `^(foo|bar)$`? If this is not an option try this regex: `^(?!^(foo|bar)$).*$`.

Comment: thanks, but I can't change the behavior, since this is only the configuration for an already existing script

Comment: I added another regex to answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
scala> def isFooOrBar(s: String) = !s.matches("""foo|bar""")
isFooOrBar: (s: String)Boolean

scala> isFooOrBar("foo")
res4: Boolean = false

scala> isFooOrBar("bar")
res5: Boolean = false

scala> isFooOrBar("foof")
res6: Boolean = true
```

Comment: `def isFooOrBar(s: String) = !s.matches("""foo|bar""")` should be enough

Comment: @sschaef,  Good call.  Updated.

Comment: thank you guys, but I can't change the script. I need the regex for the configuration of the script.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern works `^(?!(foo|bar)$)`. A testing example:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

object NotRE extends App {
  val p = Pattern.compile("^(?!(foo|bar)$)");

  val test = Seq("foo", "bar", "1foo", "foo1", "2bar", "bar2", "3bar3", "3foo3");

  print(test map ((x: String) => (x, p.matcher(x).find())));
}
```